# Views in subdirectories with expressjs

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

I've got a pretty basic expressjs application with the `/` route loading a view located in `views/main/`. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "main/index" in views directory "/Users/n0pe/Sync/src/proj/views/"
```

Here's my structure (omitting the unimportant):

```
/proj
  /views
    /main
      index.hbs
  app.js
```

And here's my app.js (the important parts):

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
app.set('views',        __dirname+'/views/');
app.set('view engine',  'handlebars');
```

And here's the controller:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('main/index', {title: 'test'});
});
```

What's missing from this pretty basic setup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tested it in local and everything works. Just one mistake

from `app.set('view engine',  'handlebars');` to `app.set('view engine',  'hbs');`

my example

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views/');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('main/index',{title :"page index"});
  });

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 4):

I changed two things and it worked for me.

#### First

```
app.set('views',  [path.join(__dirname, 'views'),path.join(__dirname, 'views/main')]);
```

I passed an array to the `app.set` and added the subdirectory

#### Second

```
res.render('../main/index', {title :"page index"}, function(err, html) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I changed the directory path to relatively navigate from the parent directory.
Using the `../` makes it work somehow. Also, once you add the directory to the app.set, you can call `index` directly e.g., `res.render('index',...`

Comment: This solution can be applied in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Change your set views. it should be
**app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the file extension of the views from hbs to handlebars